# Finite Interval of Existence of Solution of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometric-integrals

I am struggling on how to prove that the interval of existence of a solution of an ODE is finite. For example, for $x'(t)=x^2+t^2$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, I have separated as follows $$\int\frac{1}{x^2+t^2}dx=\int 1 dt$$ $$\frac{1}{t}\arctan \left(\frac{x}{t} \right)=t+c$$ $$\arctan \left(\frac{x}{t} \right)=t^2+tc$$ so we get $$x(t)=t \tan(t^2+tc)$$ so $t^2+tc \in \left( \frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ which is finite for any finite value of $c$ but I am unsure of whether I did it right or am even on the right track.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that this regards to concrete problem.

Comment: You didn't separate variables properly. The integral with the measure $dx$ still has the variable $t$ in it. Let $x \to ty$ to get $$(ty)' = t^{2} (y^{2} + 1)$$ which is a [Riccati ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Comment: @Matthew It is also Riccati in its original form, a quadratic polynomial in $y$ on the right side.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yeah I know, I was only stating that the equation that I gave after the transformation was a Riccati ODE so the OP could find some information on it.

Comment: @MatthewCassell : I wanted to refer to the original equation in $x$, $x'=x^2+t^2$ is in some sense the classical (non-trivial) example for a Riccati equation.